Find the maximum of partition number, keeping row sums and column sums zero
For an $i \times s$ ($s\geq 3,\ 3\leq i \leq B_s$) matrix $M$ with row sums and column sums to be $0$, we partition each row by grouping equal elements together, and each row has a different partition.

Example 1:
$i=4, s=3$
$$\begin{bmatrix}
-2 & 1 & 1\\
1 & -2 & 1\\
1 & 1 & -2\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$
The first row forms a partition $P_1$={{1}, {2,3}}, meaning that M[1,1]≠M[1,2]=M[1,3].
The partition for the other three rows are:$P_2$={{1,3},{2}}, $P_3$={{1,2},{3}}, $P_4$={{1,2,3}}
We have $P_1 \neq P_2 \neq P_3 \neq P_4$.
Example 2:
$i=8, s=4$
$$\begin{bmatrix}
-3 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & -3 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & -3 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & -3 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & -2 & 0 \\
-1 & 1 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & -2 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$
$P_1$={{1},{2,3,4}}, $P_2$={{1,3,4},{2}}, $P_3$={{1,2,4}{3}}, $P_4$={{1,2,3},{4}}
$P_5$={{1,2,3,4}}, $P_6$={{1,2}{3}{4}}, $P_7$={{1,4}{2,3}}, $P_8$={{1}{2}{3,4}}
$P_1 \neq P_2 \neq P_3 \neq P_4 \neq P_5 \neq P_6 \neq P_7 \neq P_8$

Note that each row needs to form a different partition. And $B_s$ (Bell number) counts all possible partitions of a set with s elements, so the number of rows $i$ cannot exceed $B_s$.
We can construct $B_3 \times 3$ matrix, see comments of @GerryMyerson.
For any given column number $s$, what is the maximum row number $i$? Can we prove that such $B_s \times s$ matrix exists for any given $s$?
($B_s$ is the Bell number for $s$; it counts all possible partitions for a set with $s$ elements.See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number)

I see rows, but I don't see partitions. What do you mean? And what's the definition of $B_s$?

For $s=3$, can't you have rows $-2,1,1; 1,-2,1; 1,1 -2; -4,2,2; 2,-4,2; 2,2,-4; 6,-3,-3; -3,6,-3; -3,-3,6$?

@GerryMyerson Thank you for replying! I added the details you mentioned in the question. The matrix is under such limitation that each row has a different partition.And B_s(Bell number) is all possible partitions of a set with s elements. So we cannot have more rows than B_s. -2,1,1 and -4,2,2 have the same partition {{1}{2,3}} so we cant have that.

OK. $s=3$, $i=5$. $2,-1,-1; 3,-6,3; 4,4,-8; 0,0,0; -9,3,6$.

@GerryMyerson Yes, this works. What I really want to ask is,  can we prove that such B_s *s matrix exists for any given s?

I think it can be done by filling the first $B_s-1$ rows with pretty much anything (making sure to use a $(0,0,0,\dotsc,0)$ row but not using a row with all entries different), and then just setting the last row to make all the column sums zero. With a little luck, all the entries in that last row will be different; if they aren't, just go back and change one of the earlier rows, while keeping its partition type.

@GerryMyerson I see.Thank you very much!
